# Copying from one list to another

Tags: java, list, iterator, structure

I have a list of sets of pairs. If I use equal does it copy every set over?

```
List<HashSet<Pair>> list1 = new ArrayList<HashSet<Pair>>();
List<HashSet<Pair>> list2 = new ArrayList<HashSet<Pair>>();

list1.add(0, new HashSet<Pair>());
list1.add(1, new HashSet<Pair>());
list1.add(2, new HashSet<Pair>());
list1.add(3, new HashSet<Pair>());
```

If I do `list2 = list1`, does it copy over perfectly? Because when I use it, it crashes.

```
Iterator<Pair> it1 = list2.get(0).iterator();
Iterator<Pair> it2 = list2.get(1).iterator();
Iterator<Pair> it3 = list2.get(2).iterator();
Iterator<Pair> it4 = list2.get(3).iterator();
```

Comment: What stack trace do you get when it crashes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list2 = list1
```

This assignment simply assigns the reference `list2` to point at the same List as `list1`. (Note that there is only *one* list with two references to it.) If you want to copy the list, you need to use a copy constructor:

```
list2 = new ArrayList<HashSet<Pair>>(list1);
```

Answer (score 4):

No.  The assignment doesn't copy anything, and instead updates the list2 reference to point to list1.  So you are able to use list2 as if it were list1; however changes you make to 2 will be reflected in 1.

Comment: Is this the same for any container in java?

Comment: This is the same for any reference to any object.

Comment: Simply put, you'll **never** copy anything in Java using the assignment operator. The farthest you can get with it is assigning an `int` or similar value to another var.